# simple_form association list change by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a `CarType` model with attributes as `manufacturere` and `model`, based on which a `Car` model is specified. `Car` model has only one attribute as `color`. I have defined associations as follows:

In CarType.rb:

```
has_many :cars
```

In Car.rb:

```
belongs_to :car_type
```

I am using simple_form to create new Car instances. However, since the Car model does not have `manufacturer` and `model` attributes, I need to specify the associated `CarType` and then, specify `color`. In the form, the user should select the `manufacturer` first, to enable the list of `model`s, where the list should include only the `model`s related to that manufacturer. Then the user will specify the color.

The way I want to implemented defining the `manufacturere` and `model` for `Car` is this: I use a `select_tag` to specify the `manufacturer` first and then using jquery and ajax, I get the list of related `model`s of that `manufacturere` and then I enable the field for `model` with the list of models based on that `manufacturer`. Based on the selected model, I specify the association as well to be used later. In summary I have the following in the form for defining new `Car`:

```
= select_tag "manufacturer", options_for_select(CarType.all.map{|s| s.manufacturer}.uniq, (f.object.car_type_id ? f.object.car_type.manufacturer : nil)), input_html: {id:'manufacturer_ajax'}

= f.association :car_type, input_html:{ id:'model_js'}
```

and for jquery I have:

```
javascript:
 $(function(){
   $("#manufacturer_ajax").change(function(){        
    $.ajax({
      url: '#{SETTINGS[:root_path]}admin/car_type/models.json',
      data: {manufacturer:$(this).val()},
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET"
    }).done(function(data){
      $("#model_js").html("<option> </option>");
      $.each(data, function(index,item){
        $("#model_js").append("<option value="+item.id+">"+item.model+"</option>");
      });
      $("#model_js").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
  });
});
```

I have checked ajax in the console and saw that it works well and gets the related models. But after ajax,`("#model_js").removeAttr("disabled");` is not doing its job and the list for `model` is still disabled.

Could you please let me know where I am making mistake? Also please let me know your opinion about the overall idea for implementing by select_tag.

Comment: 1) Does your field have the id "model_js" when the form is rendered?
2) Besides being disabled, is the list of its options updated after the ajax call?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found the problem. For simplicity, I had not included above, all the html attributes that in my codes I have used in `input_html:{ id:'model_js'}`. One of them that I was using, was making a problem. I removed it and it is working now. So in summary, using `input_html` with more than one attributes might make troubles. It needs more care.